# How would multiple people send in one transaction?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

Is it possible to have multiple inputs, from different people?

How would this be set up?

Comment: I was referring to having multiple inputs from different parties on the actual transaction log

Comment: that was a mistake, I misclicked the button 'flag'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have multiple inputs, from different people?

the bitcoin system doesn't know people - it is working with transactions, that move funds from address to address. Still the answer is "yes". You can create transactions, that spend funds from different addresses. To be more specific, we would talk about UTXO, but I think that goes beyond scope of the question, and the developers webpages have enough explanation (see reference below).
Exchanges create such transactions all the time, or also faucets. They (can) have multiple inputs, and multiple outputs as well.

> How would this be set up?

you would [follow the specification](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx) :-)
A guided example is in  the [Complex Raw Transaction](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#complex-raw-transaction) section of the developer examples.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was referring to how would two different people with different UTXOs, pool together to pay one person in one transaction? Do they just supply their signature to the input, specifying the output and I add it into my transaction?

Comment: It is possible. Bitcoin does not know "people". I try to abstract from your scenario: person a and person b want to pay person c some funds in one transaction. There are two ways to achieve: either both create the transaction together, so that there are two v_ins, and one v_out section (but I am not aware of any software which does this, so they'd have to do that manually, with all dependencies on previous tx, previous outpoint, field length...), or both use a multisig tx. The latter allows two people to send funds to a third person, and there are already some wallets supporting this concept.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. The first scenario is what I was referring to. Because no software does it as of yet, I was confused as to how it was possible. Doing it the former way would require an element of trust. Unles there is a way to do it, where I take your signed input and add it to my signed input to make a transaction to said output. Thank you for the clarity